# How to simulate browser request for dynamic data using java?

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection

When I go to a certain web page I see a lot of data I'd like to scrape.  When I "show source" the data is not there so I know it is coming in dynamically.

To find out what the chrome browser is actually sending to get the data, I press F12 to bring up the debugging console.  Then I go to the Network tab and then the XHR subtab.  Now I see a list of requests.  I click on the one that shows the data I'm looking for in the Preview tab.  Then I right-click on that request and select Copy->Copy Request Headers.

Here is what shows up when I paste into a text file:

```
GET /index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=UPDATE&FNC=LOAD&AREA=W&PageDir=0&doR=1&tx=1563305131817&bypassPage=1&test=1&_=1563305131817 HTTP/1.1
Host: charlotte.realforeclose.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://evil.com/
Referer: https://charlotte.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=07/23/2019
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: cfid=6f228aa1-bb7e-4734-92ff-39eabf23ed9b; cftoken=0; AWSELB=E7779D5F1C1F6ABE3513A5C5B6B0C754520B66675A407900314ABAC5333A52E93FD1A8D7401D89BC8D5E8B98059C8AAC5507D12A2C6ED07F7E7CB77311BD7FB09B738DB945; _ga=GA1.2.1823487290.1563231012; _gid=GA1.2.1418453663.1563231012; _gcl_au=1.1.273755450.1563231013; __utmc=65865852; __utmz=65865852.1563231014.1.1.utmcsr=realauction.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/client-sites; CF_CLIENT_CHARLOTTE_REALFORECLOSE_TC=1563285507505; __utma=65865852.1823487290.1563231012.1563300430.1563305081.3; __utmt_UA-51657054-1=1; _gat=1; testcookiesenabled=enabled; CF_CLIENT_CHARLOTTE_REALFORECLOSE_LV=1563305130572; CF_CLIENT_CHARLOTTE_REALFORECLOSE_HC=1454; __utmb=65865852.4.10.1563305081
```

Next, I follow the tutorial here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request

And my java code looks like this:

```
List<Property> scrapePropertyInfo(List<Date> auctionDates) {
    List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();
    String urlStr = "https://charlotte.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=UPDATE&FNC=LOAD&AREA=W&PageDir=0&doR=1&tx=1563305131817&bypassPage=1&test=1&_=1563305131817";
    String str = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "charlotte.realforeclose.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36");
        con.setRequestProperty("Origin", "http://evil.com/");
        con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://charlotte.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=07/23/2019");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "cfid=6f228aa1-bb7e-4734-92ff-39eabf23ed9b; cftoken=0; AWSELB=E7779D5F1C1F6ABE3513A5C5B6B0C754520B66675A407900314ABAC5333A52E93FD1A8D7401D89BC8D5E8B98059C8AAC5507D12A2C6ED07F7E7CB77311BD7FB09B738DB945; _ga=GA1.2.1823487290.1563231012; _gid=GA1.2.1418453663.1563231012; _gcl_au=1.1.273755450.1563231013; __utmc=65865852; __utmz=65865852.1563231014.1.1.utmcsr=realauction.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/client-sites; CF_CLIENT_CHARLOTTE_REALFORECLOSE_TC=1563285507505; __utma=65865852.1823487290.1563231012.1563300430.1563305081.3; __utmt_UA-51657054-1=1; _gat=1; testcookiesenabled=enabled; CF_CLIENT_CHARLOTTE_REALFORECLOSE_LV=1563305130572; CF_CLIENT_CHARLOTTE_REALFORECLOSE_HC=1454; __utmb=65865852.4.10.1563305081");

        //handle cookies
        //String cookiesHeader = con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        //List<HttpCookie> cookies = HttpCookie.parse(cookiesHeader);
        //CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        //cookies.forEach(cookie -> cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, cookie));
        //con.disconnect();
        //con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();       //create new connection with cookies
        //con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", StringUtils.join(cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies(), ";"));

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(str);
        }
        System.out.println("Url: "+urlStr);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CharlotteCtyFL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CharlotteCtyFL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

But my output is encoded gibberish.  Am I doing this right?  If so, how do I decode it?

Here is a screenshot of the output, since it won't paste
[image]

Comment: You can use `BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(InputStream in,String charsetName));` to read return bytes.Confirm what the charset the returned bytes uses and then use the same charset decode it.

Comment: Well I looked at the Response Header and it showed Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 so I added UTF-8 as the charsetName but still getting gibberish.  I wonder if it is gzip because of the Accept-Encoding Request Property?

Comment: Comment out `con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");` and try again.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I did that and then I got something I could read, but it was an empty set.  The real trick was changing testcookiesenabled in the cookie from enabled to disabled.  Then I got the results!